# Angular 5 Material Sidenav not closing on backdrop click

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following markup:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container (backdropClick)="close()" class="dashboard-mat-sidenav-container">

  <mat-sidenav #leftSideNav mode="side"
   opened="true" position="start"
    [fixedInViewport]="true">
    <ak-left-nav></ak-left-nav>
  </mat-sidenav> 

  <mat-sidenav-content>        
     <ak-header>
      <ak-search-button (click)="searchSideNav.open()"></ak-search-button>
     </ak-header>    
     <ak-dashboard></ak-dashboard>

     <ak-left-nav-btn (click)="leftSideNav.open()"></ak-left-nav-btn>

     <div class="wb-menu-button" id="wb-button-search-mobile" (click)="searchSideNav.open()">        
        <div><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
     </div>

     <mat-sidenav #searchSideNav position="end">       
       Search bar  
     </mat-sidenav> 

  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is: Have 2 sidenavs in the screen: one always open, the other that can be toggled between open and close.

The problem is that with this code, I have been able to achieve the above, but now the toggle-able sidenav doesn't close on the click of backdrop (backdrop means mat-sidenav-container). I've added an explicit method that should respond to clicks on the backdrop, but it doesn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<mat-sidenav #searchSideNav position="end">` needs to be outside the `<mat-sidenav-content>` element.